# Text change event for textbox not updating assigned value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I am building a shopping portal where I need to accept quantity of products and pass it to an action named order

[image]

As you can see in picture above, I added a textbox for accepting quantity for each of the product, then I built an actionlink using following code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Order Now", "OrderNow", "ShoppingCart", new { id = item.prod_id, qty = @quantity }, new { style = "color: white;" })
```

to get quantity I added new int quantity attribute to view, as

```
int quantity = 1;
```

but how to update this quantity variable when users change the text in qty textbox.

Below is my View code:

```
  @Html.TextBox("qty","", new { id=@item.prod_name, placeholder="Qty", style="width:20px; height:15px; font-size:small;" })
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#@item.prod_name').change(function () {

                        }
                    });
                </script>
                @Html.ActionLink("Order Now", "OrderNow", "ShoppingCart", new { id = item.prod_id, qty = @quantity }, new { style = "color: white;" })
```

Here is my controller action method

```
  public ActionResult OrderNow(int id, int qty)
    {
        if (Session["cart"] == null)
        {
            List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
            cart.Add(new Item(p.FirstOrDefault(), qty));
            Session["cart"] = cart;
            return RedirectToAction("ViewCart", new { ids = p.FirstOrDefault().prod_sub_cat_id });
        }
        else
        {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];

                cart[index].quantity = qty;
            Session["cart"] = cart;
            return RedirectToAction("ViewCart", new { ids = p.FirstOrDefault().prod_sub_cat_id });
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to update it using javascript/jquery, or use a form to post the value.

Comment: use hidden field update its value using javascript/jquery on event onchange of text box

Comment: @StephenMuecke see my view code and suggest where do i  need to change

Comment: Whats your controller ? How is it being posted ? How is quantity being assigned in the `GET`? Do you want a live update or is this for a `POST` only ..

Comment: @gerdi see my edit.. added my action method.. do i need to update routes to accept two paramters

Comment: @MayurAMuley .. Why are you using `@Textbox()` how will that pass to the `POST` if it is not assigned to the model? Should it not be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.quantity)`

Comment: If you are not using a form you need to manually assign the model properties as they are changed to the link that you want to use to pass those values. I would use a form and an submit button. This stuff is getting posted right? So why not? It encapsulates everything quite nicely

Comment: @gerdi My quantity is in view model, and my view is strongly binded with product model, how it can post other model than products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want a link to a GET method here. Your modifying data (and would not want this to be added to the browser history) so you should be posting the data. For each product, add a form element with a textbox for the quantity and a submit button for the 'Order Now` action (style it to look like a link if you want)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OrderNow", "ShoppingCart", new { id = item.prod_id })
{
  <input type="text" class="???" name="qty" placeholder="Qty" />
  <input type="submit" value="Order Now" class="???" />
}
```

Side notes:

1. Add class names and use css rather than including inline styles such
   as `style="width:20px; height:15px; font-size:small;"`
2. You could also use `@Html.TextBox("qty", new { id = "",
   @class="???", placeholder = "Qty")`, but note the `id = ""` which
   removes the `id` attribute to prevent invalid html due to duplicates

Comment: Let me try this. Do i need to change my controller signature?

Comment: Just another note (although its no longer relevant) but never generate a script for each item like that. The correct approach would have been to add a class name to the textbox (not an `id`) and have a single script such as `$('.qty').change(function() { var link = $(this).next('a'); ...});` (or a similar relative selector to get the associated link)

Comment: My bad! From now onwards, I'll take care of this.!